# AWS Cognito, retrieve old edited custom value

Tags: amazon-cognito

I edited a custom value on Cognito with this command:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id us-east-2_XXXX --username some_email@gmail.com --user-attributes Name="custom:address",Value="Some values"
```

But I put the wrong email. Is there a way to rollback that change or retrieve the old data for that user?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to roll back the change and the data will not be available unless you had it stored elsewhere prior.